# Facebook / LinkedIn share page - https opengraph issues

Tags: facebook, https

I have added the Open Graph meta data to my **functions.php**:

```
function insert_fb_in_head() {
  global $post;
  if ( !is_singular())
    return;
        echo '<meta property="fb:admins" content="PAGE_ID"/>';
        echo '<meta property="og:title" content="' . get_the_title() . '"/>';
        echo '<meta property="og:type" content="article"/>';
        echo '<meta property="og:url" content="' . get_permalink() . '"/>';
        echo '<meta property="og:site_name" content="SITE_TITLE"/>';
        echo '<meta property="og:image" content="' . $default_image . '"/>';
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'insert_fb_in_head', 5 );
```

However when pasting from HTTPS, it does not fetch the OG data. Sharing from HTTP works perfectly fine.

I also tried adding:

```
og:image:secure_url
```

Didn't work either.

[image: HTTP vs HTTPS LinkedIn Share]

Comment: Has this question been resolve? I assume there has been quite a few changes for Open Graph since the time this was originally asked.

Comment: @EthanJinksO'Sullivan Yes sorry the issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the Open Graph Debugger:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Result:

```
Inferred Property   The... property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
```

So all I had to do:

```
<meta property="og:..." content="http://www.mywebaddress.com"/>
<meta property="og:..." content="http://www.mywebaddress.com" />
```

That extra space between **" />** was the fix. Weird.

Also remember LinkedIn caches the data for **7 days**, so check later on the week if fully resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I am having a very similar problem for which you can see detailed info and diagnosis here: http://www.themastfarminn.com/php-prob/

I sent in a support ticket to hosting company and here is what they replied:

|||||||||||||||||||||||||||

We recently updated our Mod Security settings for all signature accounts. This will block any requests that do not include the user-agent string in the HTTP header and send a forbidden response. To fixed the problem you will need to update your script (curl script) to include a user-agent string and the server will then allow the connection. For reference, you might to view the link below:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537503%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

|||||||||||||||||||||||||||

That was not at all helpful to me as I have no clue about how to do what they say needs to be done, but perhaps you do.

Comment: Sounds to complex for what it is. See my answer above if it helps you in any way. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and sysadmin was able to resolve it. The issue with our site was a server misconfiguration, when I ran our pages with HTTPS in validator.w3.org it would return a handshake alert error, same page run with HTTP was fine.  This error was causing pages entered on linkedin with HTTPS to not be scraped, but the same page entered with HTTP worked fine.

Check your page on https://validator.w3.org/.

Note I believe linkedin does not distinguish between HTTP and HTTPS, but the engine reading the pages may find an error in HTTPS and not read tags. Linkedin caches OG meta data for 1 week.